# how to use webpack to load script from node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, loader

I need to use the script-loader to load a script from node_modules. I've tried doing the following require in my client_entry.js

```
require('script-loader!canvas-to-blob');
```

but I get the following error in my browser:

```
VM1702:1Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at eval (eval at module.exports (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:164122:9), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:164122:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:164108:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:669:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:48:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:20:30)
    at http://patientwisdom-dev.com:8080/index.js:40:18
```

I also tried:

```
require('script-loader!canvas-to-blob/index.js');
```

still no luck

fyi, this works for js files with a relative path:

```
require('script-loader!./test.js'); // works
```

but not for stuff from node_modules

Answer (score 1):

You just need the complete relative path including `node_modules`.

Depending on where in your project your js file is relative to `node_modules` it might look something like this.

```
require('script-loader!../../node_modules/canvas-to-blob/index.js');
```